# Adding a new property into a javascript object based on existing property of siblings

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, lodash

Lets say I have a complex array of objects like this:

```
[
  {
    "title": "Fundamentals",
    "order": 1,
    "lessonRef": "fundamentals",
    "children": [
      {
        "title": "History",
        "order": 1,
        "lessonRef": "history",
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "title": "NEW NODE 1",
        "lessonRef": "NEW NODE 1 STUB",
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "title": "Math",
        "order": 2,
        "lessonRef": "math",
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "title": "NEW NODE 2",
        "lessonRef": "NEW NODE 2 STUB",
        "children": []
      }
      {
        "title": "Geography",
        "order": 3,
        "lessonRef": "geography",
        "children": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Basics",
    "order": 2,
    "lessonRef": "basics",
    "children": []
  }
]
```

How do I:

1. Iterate through each of the nodes,
2. Detect that there is a `new node` without the `order` field and give it the next number based on where it is in the array,
3. Then increment every existing sibling after that while also
4. Take into account any other newly added nodes below it?

I'm looking for a lodash method to get me started before I go head first into doing it with pure javascript.

EDIT: provided my solution -- in my case, array order is guaranteed but I will extend the question to the case where order is not guaranteed.

Comment: It sounds like you just want to reassign every order number to be its array position.  All you have to do there is iterate each array and assign the order property to be the array position.  And, you can make it recursive on each child array.

Comment: oh wow. that would definitely work. let me try it out.

Comment: Yep, that definitely works. Just did a simple recursive function using array positions. I guess I'll put that in my question and update it with if array order is not guaranteed. Thanks.

Comment: The protocol here on this forum is to NOT put the answer into your question.  If you've found an answer that is not already supplied, then put the answer into your own answer (you are allowed to answer your own question).  Questions should be questions.  Answers should be answers.

Answer (score 0):

if this is what you wanna do:

```
var yourArray = yourDataArr
var arr1 = []


//fix children first
_.each(yourArray, function(item) {
    if(item.children) item.chilren = fixArr(children)
    arr1.push(item)
})


//fix your array
yourArray = fixArr(arr1)


//fix function
function fixArr(arr) {

    var res = []
    var prevOrder

    _.each(arr, function(item) {


        var currentOrder = item.order

        if(!currentOrder) {
            item.order =  prevOrder?prevOrder + 1:1
            prevOrder = item.order + 0
        }
        res.push(item)

    })

    return res

}

//or maybe this is you want
function fixArrAlt(arr) {

    var res = []
    var order = 1

    _.each(arr, function(item) {

        item.order =  order + 0
        res.push(item)
        order ++

    })

    return res

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Going with @jfriend00's suggestion, I just mapped through all elements in array recursively and assigned the order to be the index:

```
function reapplyOrder(array){
  return _.map(array, function (val, i) {
    val.order = i+1;
    if(val.children.length > 0){
      val.children = reapplyOrder(val.children);
    }
    return val;
  });  
}
$scope.array = reapplyOrder($scope.array);
```

In my case, array order is guaranteed but I will extend the question to the case where order is not guaranteed.